# Is there an "easy" way to download my inbox messages via a script?

Tags: support, global-inbox, scripts

As the question indicates, I am wondering if there is an easy way to automate getting my inbox messages via a script.  I'm not able to visit each day (as my lack of "Fanatic" badge would indicate), but I'd like to know if someone left a message or a comment that is waiting for my response.  I've looked into the API to do this, but I'm not so sure this warrants registering an app with SO...

Comment: Have you tried browsing around on [Stack Apps](http://stackapps.com)?

Comment: Would receiving an email with unread inbox messages every three hours meet your needs? See the `email settings` in the inbox.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions...  I'll poke around with those features and see what I can make of it.  It might be the easiest thing, even if it isn't exactly what I was looking for.